# .htaccess deny from x.x.x.x not working with RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to restrict my ip via .htaccess file it is working fine in without `RewriteRule .* index.php [L]` i am quite confusing here and waste my whole day to solve this problem i tried the deny statement even at the begging of the file and at the end of every other htaccess statement. i mentioned my code below please help me to solve this problem.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value memory_limit 256M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000
    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
    php_flag session.auto_start off
    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off
    php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_security.c>
    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    SSLOptions StdEnvVars
</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            Header set X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
            BrowserMatch \bMSIE\s8 ie8
            Header set X-XSS-Protection: "1; mode=block" env=!ie8
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L] # When i comment this line the below code works fine but with this line i am unable to limit the site.

</IfModule>

Order deny,allow
Allow from all
Deny from 110.93.244.176
```

Comment: As an aside, you're using older (Apache 2.2) syntax for mod_access; `Require all granted ... Require not ip 110.93.244.176` would be correct for 2.4.

Comment: so what is the correct syntax? BTW it is working without `RewriteRule .* index.php [L]`

Comment: The access syntax you've got will work for now (assuming compatibility mode - of course you *could* be running Apache2.2 for all I know), but it's deprecated. What exactly are you trying to do, allow **only** your IP address, or block your IP address? Where does this .htaccess file reside btw, at the document root?

Comment: I want to actually block a country to visit my website i want wanted to check by blocking my IP address. and yeah .htaccess file is in root folder (public_html)

Comment: Blocking an entire country is a little tricky as there are a **lot** of possible IP ranges involved - see what you get when you try to block China using the [IP2Location tool](https://www.ip2location.com/free/visitor-blocker) - however, the principle for IP blocking is the same, with Apache 2.4 you just need a `<RequireAll> ... </RequireAll>` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research and pseudo code finally i found the problem the problem was Apache version i guess i just change the the code

**from**

```
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
Deny from 110.93.244.176
```

**to**

```
<RequireAll>
    Require all granted 
    Require not ip 110.93.244.176
</RequireAll>
```

Hope this will work for someone else.

Comment: Heh - fished your own wish and beat me to it... that's what I was referring to when I said you were using deprecated syntax ;)

Comment: Oh really sorry. i didn't saw your comment.. you could post your ans if you want i would appreciate and accept the answer.

Comment: Nah - it's perfectly fine on SO to answer your own question if you've found the solution... as long as there's a correct answer which might be helpful to future visitors (which there is) it's all good ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

The context is not clear for mé. Anyway, remove line `Allow from all` and try again.

Comment: i just tried after removing the allow statement and also tried after moving below deny statement. still same result

Comment: Change the order: `Order allow,deny`  Reasons for not working:  mod_access_compat.c not activated (newer apache has a new access control)  or operation denied by main configuration.